# Free tool for setting PDF display flags

Tags: gratis, pdf

I am looking for a free (free of charge; open source preferred, but not required) tool that can set the display flags of a PDF file, in particular the flag to automatically display the bookmarks list.

More specifically, it seems<sup>1</sup> that I need to set the `page mode` to `UseOutlines`.

Both GUI and command line tools are acceptable. The tool should run on Windows or be platform-independent (Java, Mono, ...).

**Background:**

I create PDF documents with [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and the [`hyperref` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), where I can define bookmarks and configure the resulting PDF file to have Acrobat Reader automatically display the bookmarks list upon opening the file.

However, I combine several of these PDF files with pages from other PDF files by using [PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/). This preserves the bookmarks (which are apparently considered a part of a page), but does not preserve the overall setting for the file to be opened with the bookmarks list visible.

<sup>1</sup>: I am not an expert on the PDF file format, so my conclusions are merely based upon looking at the raw contents of PDF files with different settings.

Comment: I'm not sure (which if why this is a comment instead of an answer), but you may be able to do this using [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/) and the `update_info` command.

Comment: @MosheKatz: That looks promising at first sight. However, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891176/pdftk-and-the-ability-to-change-the-default-view?lq=1#comment53006410_3900483) suggests the feature had not been added a month ago. Given that it had already been added to the wishlist 5 years ago, I do not expect it to be added to pdftk anytime soon :/

Comment: Apache PDFBox [seems to have this feature](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocumentCatalog.html#PAGE_MODE_USE_OUTLINES).

Comment: @baitisj: This should be an answer. While I am a bit undecided whether I will *accept* a programming library as the answer on this question (future visitors might not have any programming skills and indeed be looking for a runnable tool), it will certainly be sufficient for my own purposes and thus deserve at least my upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not a tool in the sense of a compiled and ready-to-use application, it appears that the [Apache PDFBox library](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocumentCatalog.html#PAGE_MODE_USE_OUTLINES) supports setting of the page mode to use outlines as required in your specification.

Additionally, the PDFBox library is open-source.

Comment: It seems like adding a tool to modify PDF flags would be a very useful contribution to the PDFBox project.

Comment: Will try this in the next few days, then report back.

Comment: This works - a simple `PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inFile); PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog(); catalog.setPageMode(PDDocumentCatalog.PAGE_MODE_USE_OUTLINES); doc.save(inFile.replaceFirst(".pdf", ".out.pdf"));` does everything I was looking for. As I suggested above, I will not quite select this as an accepted answer yet, for the sake of future visitors, but at least +1 for now.

Comment: I have ended up accepting this answer as it seems to be the "solution that comes closest to what I was looking for" at this time, for lack of any alternative answers.